# Permuting sparse matrices in Eigen

Tags: matrix, permutation, eigen, sparse-matrix

I want to permute the rows and columns of a sparse matrix in Eigen. Here's the code I have but it's not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat;
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}
int main() {
    PermutationMatrix<Dynamic,Dynamic> perm(5);
    MatrixXd x = MatrixXd::Random(5,5);
    SpMat y = x.sparseView();
    int dim=5;
    perm.setIdentity();
    for (int i=dim-1; i>0; --i) {
        swap (perm.indices()[i],perm.indices()[myrandom(i+1)]);
    }
    cout << "permutation\n" << perm.indices() << endl << endl;
    cout << "original x\n" << y << endl << endl;
    cout << "permuted left x \n" << perm * y << endl << endl;
    cout << "permuted right x \n" << y * perm << endl << endl;
    cout << "permuted both x \n" << perm * y * perm << endl << endl;
}
```

It permutes the rows and permutes the columns, but it doesn't do both. Does anyone know how both the columns and rows can be permuted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a symmetric permutation `P * Y * P^-1`, then the best is to use the `twistedBy` method:

```
SpMat z = y.twistedBy(perm);
```

otherwise you have to apply one and then the other:

```
SpMAt z = (perm * y).eval() * perm;
```

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted was to apply the symmetric permutation. But the problem is I end up getting `Eigen::SparseSymmetricPermutationProduct<SpMat, 3> z = y.twistedBy(perm);`. Do you know how I can modify y so that it permutes? Or how I can get the permuted y if I cannot modify y itself.

Comment: I figured it out. You can create a new variable and then use evalTo: `SpMat k; z.evalTo(k)`. I was wondering if there would be any errors if I did `z.evalTo(y)`. And how efficient either of these operations would be in terms of time and memory. Thanks.