# How do I swap both columns and rows in a symmetrical sparse matrix in C++'s Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, rcpp

I am trying achieve the following dense matrix operation for a sparse symmetrical matrix:

```
    dm.col(j).swap(dm.col(i));
    dm.row(j).swap(dm.row(i));
```

In order to interchange two columns (and rows) in a sparse symmetric matrix, I am trying to generate a permutation matrix so that I can pass it to .twistedBy():

```
    Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> P;
    P.setIdentity();
    P.col(j).swap(P.col(i));

    sm = sm.twistedBy(P);
```

Unfortunately, .col().swap() is not supported for permutation matrices. What should I do?

This question clarifies the use of .twistedBy, but does not explain how to construct a permutation matrix:
[Permuting sparse matrices in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880080/permuting-sparse-matrices-in-eigen)

I am having a hard time trying to understand the documentation of eigen:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PermutationMatrix.html

Any general help with that would be appreciated, too!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`applyTranspositionOnTheRight`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PermutationBase.html#a5f98da0712570d0c4b12f61839ae4193):

```
Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic >::PermutationMatrix P(n);
P.setIdentity();
P.applyTranspositionOnTheRight(j, i);
```